# Is it possible get feed from unofficial facebbok page?

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am able to get feeds from facebook page using its pageid and it working successfully ,but same code is not working for "unofficial facebook page".
So my question is "Is it possible get feed from unofficial facebook page?"

Comment: do you try for the same unofficial page in graph api  if it works there ,it should work in your code also.

Comment: how can i do that? means in graph api?

Comment: place the page id in the query and put access token in using add access token

Comment: I check it. it's response is "{
  "data": [
  ]
}".what it means?

Comment: it mean you get nothing in terms of data for that page ,reason may be you don't have permissions in access token

Comment: I got feed for other pages, it happens with unofficial facebook pages.